# Capture ManipulationDelta Event with ScrollViewer Inside (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have the follow XAML code:

```
<Grid ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="TranslateX" Margin="10,134,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="203" Height="120" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla "  Width="182" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla "  Width="182" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla "  Width="182" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla "  Width="182" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla "  Width="182" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
```

I need the scroll viewer for the vertical scrolling only, and I need to capture the TranslateX within the event Grid_ManipulationDela.

It seems that the ScrollViewer Suppresses all the manipulation event from it's parent.

How can I propagate (chaining) the TranslateX from the scroll viewer to the gird in my case?

NB: `IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False|True"` does not resolve the problem.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you try this <StackPanel ManipulationMode="TranslateX" >  . This link says it may solve the issue "https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d707fe74-58d3-4aee-8094-3d14c06300b6/disable-horizontalscrollmode-of-scrollviewer-and-receiving-manipulation-events-in-the-parent?forum=winappswithcsharp"

Comment: Did not resolve the issue, thanks

Comment: Did you try binding TranslateX from ScrollViewer to Grid? Like ManipulationMode="{Binding ElementName=scroll, Path=ManipulationMode}"

Comment: Interesting. Not even [UIElement.AddHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.addhandler.aspx) works. I tried adding handlers to various elements with UIElement.AddHandler which is supposed to be a way you can handle events that are marked as handled. Did not work.

Comment: I tried PointerCapture events; did not solve issue.

Comment: have you find a solution :( ?

Answer (score 0):

That happens because scrolling is being handled by the compositor thread. You can force it to handle input on the UI thread by setting `ManipulationMode` of your `ScrollViewer` to `ManipulationMode.System`.